# Fresh install of Magento 1.9.2.3 has broken CSS? It doesn't look right

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, css, installation

I just installed Magento in my laptop. I followed the instructions here:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_req-prereq_centos.html .

When I went to my browser to install Magento I saw that it looked like this:
[image]

I have tried deleting magento and installing again. Downloaded a new installer then installed again, but it still won't work.

Thanks.

UPDATE:
This is my console log:
[image]

And here is my Network:
[image]

Comment: if you open dev tools on chrome f12 can you post screetshot of console errors

Comment: check if you have a var folder created and the permissions are set to 777

Comment: Yes, it is set to 777.

Comment: Try to use another browser or clean cache of current one.

Comment: I did both already :( @RomanGlushko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem it's related with permissions, try to follow this guide:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html

If don't work try adding this line in .htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "(\.css)$"> 
AddType text/css .css 
Header set Content-Type text/css 
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: I followed the instructions, nothing happened :(

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot of console tab  and network tab?, please

Comment: Hi, I updated my post.

Comment: Try to add in apache configuration httpd.conf or similar this directive:
AddType text/css .css

Comment: Where should I add `AddType text/css .css`  in httpd.conf?

Comment: in your apache configuration in my case: /etc/apache2/httpd.conf. Check with phpinfo() or try with this link: http://www.commanigy.com/blog/2011/6/8/finding-apache-configuration-file-httpd-conf-location

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35248/discussion-between-magentouser-and-osrecio).

Comment: We can chat, ok go!